# How to accumulate results from has_many relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, has-many, activemodel

I want to get a list of all `boards` from selected `projects` with just one line of code:

```
boards = projects.boards
```

How to do it?

Currently I iterate individually over each project, get its boards and accumulate results in array (code below)

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :boards
end

class Board < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
end

class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :projects
end

projects = @account.projects.where("SOME_CONDITION")

# my current code:
boards = []
projects.each do |project|
  boards << project.boards
end

# wanted code:
boards = projects.boards # <--- How to achieve it?
```

Comment: will this help: `boards = @account.projects.where("SOME_CONDITION").includes(:boards).collect(&:boards).compact.flatten`

Comment: Yes, it helps :) Why do I need to use `.includes(:boards)` part? It seems that your code works fine without it, i.e. `@account.projects.where("SOME_CONDITION").collect(&:boards).compact.flatten`

Comment: `.includes(:boards)` is basically eagerloading concept. this might helps http://blog.arkency.com/2013/12/rails4-preloading/.  it optimizes the query and load the association recods using `IN` query rather than running individual queries to fetch boards for each project. It will fetch all boards using IN query on `board.project_id`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I am getting it right, you want to have boards for an account's projects. You need to add few more lines to your models.

1.

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base  
   has_many :boards  
   belongs_to :account   
end
```

2.

```
class Board < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :project  
   belongs_to :account, through: project  
end
```

3.

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :projects
   has_many :boards, through: :projects

   def projects_boards(project_ids)  
     self.boards.where(boards.project_id: project_ids)  
   end  
end
```

And then just call it like this:
`boards= @account.boards`
Edited call to suit your needs:
`boards = @account.projects_boards(projects.map(&:id))`

Comment: It is good solution but it does not satisfy the `where` caluse in the OP.

Comment: you can add where after boards...like this:  
boards = @account.boards.where('projects.id > ? and boards.created_at > ?',some_id,1.month.ago)

Comment: It's indeed a good solution, but it still did not solve my main code's problem - expressiveness and shortness. In your code I need to do this to get boards from selected projects: `@account.boards.where('projects.id IN ?', projects.map(&:id))`     Unfortunately `@account.boards` returns ALL boards from ALL projects... It would be nice if I could simply type `projects.boards` and it will return ALL boards associated with `projects` array

Comment: >**If I am getting it right, you want to have projects for an account's projects**  I want to have boards for a selected projects

Comment: Sorry you can get results this ways but you can have an instance method in Account Model...I edited my answer for it..

Answer (score 0):

**Use This Syntax**

projects = @account.projects.where("SOME_CONDITION").last.boards

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `includes` AR statement to fetch all boards related to each project

```
Project.a_scope.includes(:boards).each do |project|
  projects.boards.do_something
end
```

will fetch all boards that are related to the projects you want, by using two SQL queries.

`select * from projects where ...`

`select * from boards where boards.project_id in (1,2,3,4...)`

If all you want is a list of boards you can do that by yourself

```
project_ids = Project.a_scope.pluck(:id)
boards = Board.where(id: project_ids)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :boards
end

class Board < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
end

class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :projects
  has_many :boards, through: :projects
end
```

Let's just say

```
SOME_CONDITION = "projects.state = 'active'"
```

Just use this:

```
@account.boards.where(SOME_CONDITION)
```